# Use localized parameter and normal Text in

Tags: swiftui

how I can make this Output?

```
Text(format: LocalizedStringKey("ImpressEmail %@"), ": app.example@emample.org")
```

The result should be :

Email: app.example@example.org

In my localizationfile I have the following string::

```
"ImpressEmail" = "Email";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use this in .string file

```
"ImpressEmail %@" = "Email: %@";
```

and call it like this

```
Text("ImpressEmail \("email")")
```